# How to print elements of a std::vector<std::any> vector in C++?

Tags: c++

The system is able to figure out the type of each element using `a.type().name()` but seriously is not able to print them?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <any>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
    
template<typename Last>
void addElement(std::vector<std::any>& container, Last last) {
    std::cout << "Last = " << last << std::endl;
    container.push_back(last);
}

template<typename First, typename... Rest>
void addElement(std::vector<std::any>& container, First first, Rest... rest) {
    std::cout << "Elem = " << first << std::endl;
    container.push_back(first);
    addElement(container, rest...);
}

template<typename... Ts>
std::vector<std::any> createAnyVector(Ts... ts) {
    std::vector<std::any> container;
    addElement(container, ts...);
    return container;
}

int main() {
    std::cout << "ANYVECTOR" << std::endl;

    std::vector<std::any> container = createAnyVector("Hello", 3.14, 'A', true, 42);

    std::cout << "Number of elements in container = " << container.size() << std::endl; // 5 correct.

    for (const auto& a : container) {

        std::cout << a.type().name() << ", " << "HERE?" << std::endl;
    }
}
```

If I just write `a` at the place where now `HERE?` stands, it returns the error:

```
No operator << matches these operands
operand types are: std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char>> << const << std::any
```

Comment: You can't print it, because what if it's a type that's impossible to print?

Comment: The error is telling you that there is no `operator<<` defined for printing a `std::any`, which is true. `std::any::type()` returns a `std::type_info&` for RTTI of whatever type is assigned to the `std::any` at runtime, but `operator<<` has to be known at compile-time. Do you expect `std::any` to define an `operator<<` that handles every possible type that might be assigned to it at runtime?  That is not possible.

Comment: What Remy said. You have to design operator or other mechanism which would select proper data type of those which are possible _in your_ program at run time, it's easier to do with tagged unions like `std::variant`

Comment: Not only you cannot print them, you can hardly do anything with them. What is the common interface of all types? Nothing. Use `std::variant`.

Comment: From your profile, I'm guessing you don't dig into lower level stuff. If you find this limitation incredulous, it might be enlightening to implement `std::any` yourself and see why it's the case, and what price you have to pay to have this functionality. Also, `std::any` is almost always wrong in C++.

Answer (score 6):

As the comments point out, you cannot do anything directly with `std::any`, you can just hold them.

If you control the API and have the option to create a wrapper around `std::any`, you can maintain a function pointer to print the current `std::any`'s contents like so:

```
struct printable_any {
  template <class T>
  printable_any(T&& t) : m_val(std::forward<T>(t)) {
    m_print_fn = [](std::ostream& os, const std::any& val) {
      os << std::any_cast<std::decay_t<T>>(val);
    };
  }

private:
  using print_fn_t = void(*)(std::ostream&, const std::any&);
  std::any m_val;
  print_fn_t m_print_fn;
  
  friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const printable_any& val) {
    val.m_print_fn(os, val.m_val);
    return os;
  }
};
```

Note that even with this, you cannot take a random `std::any` and print it, you have to construct it yourself along with the function pointer.

Usage:

```
int main() {
    std::vector<printable_any> vals {
        "Hello", 3.14, 'A', true, 42
    };

    for (auto& v : vals) {
        std::cout << v << '\n';
    }
}
```

Prints

```
Hello
3.14
A
1
42
```

https://godbolt.org/z/o1sejrv1e

Answer (score 2):

Well, what would this print:

```
struct Foo {
  void *p;
};

any v = Foo{};
cout << v << '\n'; // what should this print?
```

There is no `toString` equivalent in C++. If you want that behavior, you may create your own hierarchy:

```
struct Printable {
    virtual void print(ostream&) const = 0;
};

auto& operator<<(ostream& os, any const& obj) {
    any_cast<Printable const&>(obj).print(os);
    return os;
}
```

Or customize it as you wish and handle the error cases as you like, also add special cases for the integer types if you want, etc.

Comment: what's about `std::to_string`?

Comment: @0dminnimda [std::to_string](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_string) only works for 9 built in types. It's not a generic way to convert everything to string.

Answer (score 0):

Does the vector have to be of type any or are you allowed to at least specify the kind of types that are stored in the vector? Because if you can at least specify which types are allowed, I recommend using **std::variant**.
example: `std::vector<variant<int, string>> myVectorVariant`;

After that, you can actually print to the console the items in your vector through the use of std::get_if from std::variant. copy-able function below to output your vector for the most of the main primitive types: int, float, char, string.

```
#include <variant>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void printVectorVariantValues(vector<variant<int, float, char, string>> arg) {
  try {
      for (auto val : arg) {
          if (const auto intPtr (get_if<int>(&val)); intPtr) 
              cout << *intPtr << " ";
          else if (const auto floatPtr (get_if<float>(&val)); floatPtr)
              cout << *floatPtr << " ";
          else if (const auto charPtr (get_if<char>(&val)); charPtr)
              cout << *charPtr <<  " ";
          else if (const auto stringPtr (get_if<string>(&val)); stringPtr) 
              cout << *stringPtr << " ";
      }    
  } catch (bad_variant_access err) {
      cout << "something" << " ";
  }
  
  cout << "DONE" << endl;
}

int main() {
    vector<variant<int, float, char, string>> myVectorVariant = {1, 2, 'a', 'b', 3, 0.4f, 0.5f, "c", "DeF", 0.6f, "gHi", "JkL" };
    printVectorVariantValues(myVectorVariant);
    return 0;
}

/* 
output below: 
1 2 a b 3 0.4 0.5 c DeF 0.6 gHi JkL DONE
*/
```

Comment: Though correct, this really doesn't answer the question of how to print a **`std::any`** object. That said, for `std::variant` printing, it'd be far easier to use `std::visit` so that you don't need to know any of the types, or have n `if` branches. Basically just `std::visit([](const auto& v){ std::cout << v << " "; }, val);`

Comment: @Human-Compiler - yes I agree my answer doesn't directly answer the question, but provides an alternative to said issue. And as you may agree along with the original comments under OP's question, the underlying issue is you can't print an `std::any` type unless you underwent wrapper implementation as another answer pointed out. Thus I suggested a different approach that could work better.

Comment: @Human-Compiler - Additionally, I also agree with your second statement that `std::visit` is a simpler implementation to my suggestion, but first, I only wrote in such a verbose way for educational purposes in case OP doesn't understand `std::variant` itself. And second, while not needing to know all types helps for code simplicity, in actual debugging on industry-level code, `std::visit` actually present technical debt in the fact that the developer debugging said issue won't know what types their API they may or may not control requires.

Comment: _"`std::visit` actually present technical debt..."_ -- citation _really_ needed. Debuggers tell you what types you are operating with, there isn't much question there. It isn't hard to get the type name even for logging purposes (even without RTTI), and since it's `std::variant`, the developers very much **do** know what types they are operating with. It's a little alarming that you suggest some form of technical debt on a constant-time solution like `std::visit` over an else-if ladder that queries RTTI repeatedly. I vaguely get "for educational purposes", but not the rest of that statement.

Comment: You just contradicted yourself. "It's a little alarming that you suggest some form of technical debt" and "It isn't hard to get the type name even for logging purposes". The fact that you, point out clearly that more implementation is required just to even get your types, and still don't even realize what your statement suggests alarms myself. I was merely presenting the alternative that my else if helps any developer know their types quicker.

Comment: Yes debuggers give you types you're operating with, but not on cases where the code is working and you're still figuring out the source of the issue. Lastly, yes, with variant, developer know what types they are WORKING with, but not with the data being processed at that moment of time; that still requires a query.